# Debian 8 - choppy sound

Tags: debian, audio, gnome3

I've installed both Debian 8 and Windows 7 on my pc. The thing is, Debian audio drivers produce really choppy sounds. Windows works fine.

After trying some methods from google, I actually feel more frustrated. None of them works, like [this article](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/) mentions.

I'm not sure which sorts of information I need to provide so please feel free to ask me for any required information. I really appreciate your help.

### Edit

#### Audio card info:

> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

I've tested with mp3 files and youtube videos running on Chrome HTML5 player,  Debian built-in Videos player and vlc media player. They produce the sounds that's similar to listening to music online with 1KB/s network speed.

Comment: What hardware do you use? What media applications? What have you tried?

Comment: @schaiba *What hardware do you use?* Not sure which kinds of hardware are you asking for? Audio cards? Please give me the exact command for retrieving the info. *What media aplications?* Both built-in Debian media application and Chrome's media applications (HTML5 + flash). *What have you tried?* 5 methods listed in the link.

Comment: Clearly, more information is needed like what do you mean by choppy, what audio-card/s, Mobo, which media-players, etc.

Comment: @WeareBorg I've updated my question. Please give me the exact command for any further required information.

Comment: Can you try this command : `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` . This will kill your pulse-audio and reload alsa.

Comment: @WeareBorg I got the error `command alsa not found`.

Comment: By any chance you removed any packages? Do you know which ones? Okay, then give this command, `sudo apt-get install alsa alsa-utils` . Reboot. Then lemme know

Comment: @WeareBorg No, I haven't touched any alsa packages. I think Debian 8 doesn't have this command by default. Do you mean the command `alsactl` instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36128/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-tresdin).

Answer (score 4):

Please provide more information about your hardware:

If we are talking built-in audio:

`lspci | grep -i audio`

If you are using a USB sound card:

`lsusb`

If this is a laptop or a brand desktop, the model will help as well.
If you built your own PC, what is the motherboard or sound card you use.

also, ensure the mixer is not muted, issue `alsamixer` ... ensure you have the correct card, as printed at the top, if not, in alsamixer, hit F6.

I hope this helps.

Update, op has provided details. This looks like what is [described in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling):

#### Glitches, skips or crackling

The newer implementation of the PulseAudio sound server uses timer-based audio scheduling instead of the traditional, interrupt-driven approach.

Timer-based scheduling may expose issues in some ALSA drivers. On the other hand, other drivers might be glitchy without it on, so check to see what works on your system.

To turn timer-based scheduling off add `tsched=0` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Then restart the PulseAudio server:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

Do the reverse to enable timer-based scheduling, if not already enabled by default.

If you are using Intel's IOMMU and experience glitches and/or skips, add `intel_iommu=igfx_off` to your kernel command line.

Some Intel audio cards using the snd-hda-intel module need the otions `vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0`. In order to set them permanently, create/modify the `/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf` including the line below.

```
options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: True, but comments are restrained, character-count-wise.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've updated my question with the info produced from your suggested command.